# How to asynchronously download 1000 images?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I downloaded around 1000 images from URLs to the iPhone file system, but I'd like to do it asynchronously. Currently I'm using this code:

```
-(void)saveImageInFile:(NSString *)imageName image:(UIImage *)img{

    // add the images in the file
    NSData *tmpData;

    if ([self.constImageType isEqualToString:@"png"]) {
        tmpData = UIImagePNGRepresentation (img);
    }

    else if ([self.constImageType isEqualToString:@"jpg"]) {
        tmpData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.7f);
    }

    NSString *path = [self.documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", imageName,self.constImageType]];
    //NSLog(path);
    [tmpData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am doing something similar with a lot more images than 1000. I am storing the url's for the images in core data and then getting an `NSArray` of all the records where the record attribute `imageDownloaded = NO`. While downloading the images I set that record's `imageDownloaded = YES` so if the app needs to restart it can pick up where it left off.

Here is a small example of whats happening. I am using Grand Central Dispatch to background this process so I am not blocking the main thread.

```
__block NSArray *records; //...get records

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        for (NSManagedObject *obj in records) {
            NSString *imageName = [obj valueForKey:@"filename"];

            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[obj valueForKey:@"remote_path"],imageName]];
            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
            NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:NULL error:NULL];
            [responseData writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentsDirectory,imageName] atomically:NO];
            [obj setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"imageDownloaded"];
        }
    });
```

More Information on Grand Central Dispatch
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html

Comment: my query is that i have around 1000 urls in the NSMutableArray .. can u tell me where can i place all the links.. and can u give me the full function i am very thankful because its very hard to me to understand that but really i appreciate your work its very good work and thanks

Comment: please helo ne MobileOverlord i am very thankful if your reply my above query in your code reply please because i don't go outsite the apple offical and public library. thanks

Comment: I can help come up with a more extensive example in a few hours. I'll come back with a more complete function later this evening.

Comment: thanks MobileOverload thats great i am waiting for your reply. Thanks soo much

Comment: can you please tell me mobileoverload you have told me to answer it with couple of hours i am waiting here then i will accept this solution

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you download https://github.com/ZarraStudios/ZDS_Shared and do

```
// queue download
[[ZSAssetManager singleton] queueAssetForRetrievalFromURL:url]; 

// recover the download from the file system
UIImage *imagen = [[ZSAssetManager singleton] imageForURL:url];
```

Why use this library?

- It throttles/suspends/resume the downloads based on the available bandwidth and network 
  status. Note that it uses a NSOperationQueue that can be suspended (unlike blocks).
- It handles generating a file name from a hash of the URL to avoid collisions.
- On application start it reads into memory the list of files already cached.
- It optionally allows caching when the application goes to the background.
- You can set an expiration date for files (or no expiration).
- It flushes the memory cache if the application gets a memory warning because you are reading UIImages from the cache too fast.
- It is easy to use (just the 2 lines above).

If you want to roll your own solution, it may help you to read the source code of that library since they already implemented all that.

Answer (score 0):

Read about [Grand Central Dispatch (GCD)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html).

Get one of the defaults queue and put your code into that queue using blocks. If you are not familiar with blocks read [Blocks Programming Topic](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxGettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH7-SW1).

Here is a short example:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0);

dispatch_async(queue, ^{
// This is a BLOCK. Put code here to download images in background...
}
```