# How to cache images in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimage

I'm writing an app that loads several images from a server, and I need to cache that images for next times to load faster that images.

I found [HJCache](http://www.markj.net/hjcache-iphone-image-cache/) and [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) but both fails. Does anyone know any other method to save images in cache that works?

Thanks!

ps: sorry for my english, I know it's bad

Comment: It is not those external library's fault. If I remember correctly, last time when I develop for 5.0/5.0.1, `NSURLRequest` always uses the same cache policy no matter what value is specified in the `cachePolicy:` field.

Comment: Apple added NSCache for this. See: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: At first time loading of images, save images in document directory and use these images from them instead of requesting again

Comment: see this:http://www.makebetterthings.com/iphone/image-caching-in-iphone-sdk/

Comment: I have never heard of NSCache, I hope cached data is not released when the application is closed. Thanks!

Comment: Using ZDS_Shared: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9166989/412916

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same Problem I had faced and I found solution after lots of R&D.

Solution is make us of `SDWebImage` library.

You can find it from https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Just Integrate its All files in your project.

Follow step given in documentation(Specified in above link).

Good Luck.